# Append Content in cs cart thank you page?

Tags: cs-cart

How to append content after order submit with my custom database
table information via addon. Can you please add detailed explanation about hooks for both php and tpl hook for order submit in cs cart.

I find out order.post.tpl via addon hooks in docs example.

Answer (score 0):

#PHP

- file
  `app/addons/my_changes/controllers/frontend/checkout.post.php`
- content:

```
<?php

if ( !defined('BOOTSTRAP') ) { die('Access denied'); }

if($mode == 'complete' && !empty($_REQUEST['order_id'])){
    /* add your code here */
}
```

---

#TPL

- file `design/themes/[THEME_NAME]/templates/addons/my_changes/hooks/checkout/order_confirmation.post.tpl`

---

PS: The implementation is done base on My Changes add-on